# Comprehension over the properties of an object + callback

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

At first I was a little confused about what was happening with the following code:

```
people =
  jim: 'Jim'
  james: 'James'

for k, v of people

  setTimeout( ( -> console.log(k) ), 300 )

#OUTPUT
#james
#james
```

JavaScript version:

```
var people = {
  jim: 'Jim',
  james: 'James'
};


for(var k in people){

  setTimeout( function(){ console.log(k); }, 300 );

};

//OUTPUT
//james
//james
```

But I guess by the time console.log(k) gets executed k has already changed? How do you fix it so the output is "jim, james"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into classic JavaScript closure issues.  See the section about "closure wrappers" in the "Loops and Comprehensions" section of the [CoffeeScript documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#loops).

The CoffeeScript solution to your problem is the `do` keyword:

```
for k, v of people
  do (k) -> 
    setTimeout( ( -> console.log(k) ), 300 )
```

Since you included the Javascript version of the problem, the Javascript solution would be like this:

```
for(var k in people){
  (function(k) { setTimeout( function(){ console.log(k); }, 300 ); })(k);
};
```

But this is ugly as sin, so I prefer this approach if I were to do it in JS:

```
var delayedLog = function(k) {
  setTimeout( function(){ console.log(k); }, 300 );
};

for(var k in people){
  delayedLog(k);
};
```

Comment: Crap, it's actually well documented on the CoffeeScript website. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.